# Playwright - add timeout before performing operation

Tags: automated-tests, playwright

I have a while loop that runs some code whilst a selctor is hidden i.e.

```
while(await page.locator('.list-empty').isHidden()) {
  // do something
}
```

How can i add a timeout here so that //do something is delayed before running?

i want to do this as i am finding the code runs too quickly and selectors cant be found...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.waitForSelector` for each selector you need to find, and it will wait for 30 seconds. Also, you can manage the amount of time it waits.